# Как проверить наличие слова в сообщении

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу бота, работающего на моем аккаунте Vk. Возникла потребность проверять сообщения на наличие запрещенных слов, например запрещенное слово "Арбуз", предложение, в котором его нужно найти: Я люблю арбуз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
bad_words = ['арбуз']
message = 'Я люблю арбуз'

for word in message.lower().split():
    if word in bad_words:
        print('Обнаружено плохое слово!')
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bad = {
    'яблоки',
    'груши',
    'помидоры'
}

s = 'Я люблю груши'
if bad & set(s.lower().split()):
  print('Это плохая строка. В ней встретились слова: ' + ', '.join(bad & set(s.lower().split())))
else:
  print('Это хорошая строка')
```