# Помогите, Python

Tags: python

Я получаю в чате игры сообщение с нужным словом,и хочу что бы бот на Python отвечал определенным ответом за меня. Как это сделать?

Comment: Какая платформа используется? Если это ваша игра*

Comment: Игра на мобильных устройствах, называется skullgirls.

Comment: попробуйте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1114108/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8)